# Embedded database in Java EE application

Tags: database, jakarta-ee

Good day. I'm confused about storing the embedded database in a Java EE application. I've just resolved the problem with the .properties file which can be accessed via getResource method, but where should I put my database to support portability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For portability, the appropriate way is to install the embedded database in the project directory & then specifying the relative path.

In general, you have to extract the content & specifying that path relative to the current directory as database url. Below are some examples.

- **H2 Database -** `jdbc:h2:file:relative-database-path`
- **Apache Derby -** By including required jars in classpath & configuring environment variable accordingly.
- **HSQLDB -** `jdbc:hsqldb:file:relative-database-path`